# How to properly add a PHP tag inside anchor link on PUG

Tags: php, pug

This is what i have done:

```
    a(href="http://<?php echo $link; ?>/thelink.php") thelink
```

PUG compiles to:

```
    <a href="http://&lt;?php echo $link; ?&gt;/thelink.php">thelink</a>
```

My problem are "&lt" and "&gt". How can i properly compile it to?:

```
    <a href="http://<?php echo $link; ?>/thelink.php">thelink</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Phug](https://www.phug-lang.com/#what-is-phug) when using Pug with PHP.

You can then use PHP variables (and objects) within PHP pretty easily. See this example:

```
// PHP
mixin link($href, $name)
   a(href=$href)&attributes($attributes)= $name

+link('/foo', 'foo')(class="btn")
```

PHUG transforms this to:

```
// HTML
<a class="btn" href="/foo">foo</a>
```

You can read more about this specific example [in the documentation](https://www.phug-lang.com/#attributes).

Comment: Thank you very much.. It helps me much because I don't even know that Phug is there for PHP ...

Comment: @logicshaman You're very welcome. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask. If my answer solved your problem, please go ahead an select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use "!" before "=" :

```
a(href!="http://<?php echo $link; ?>/thelink.php") thelink
```